# equation of the plane passing through the intersection of two ellipsoids

Tags: multivariable-calculus, algebraic-geometry

I want to find the equation of the plane passing the intersection of two intersecting ellipsoids. the intersection of two ellipsoids is always a ellipse. I need to find the equation of the planar surface containing this ellipse.

Does have anyone any idea in this matter?

thanks in advance for your any response

Comment: Put them in a equation and Try to cancel out the squared terms to attain a plane equation

Comment: It would have been better if you gave an example of the equations of elipsoids.

Comment: would not be that easy. there are three independent squared variables (x, y and z) in each ellipsoid's equation. You cal at most cancel out one of them and there still would be two squared variables.

Comment: The intersection of two ellipsoids is definitely not an ellipse in general.

Answer (score 0):

> **Only two similar and translated ellipsoids guarantee planar ellipse section:**

For $\lambda > 0$,

\begin{align*}
  \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}
  &= 1 \tag{1} \\
  \frac{(x-\alpha)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-\beta)^2}{b^2}+\frac{(z-\gamma)^2}{c^2}
  &= \lambda^2 \tag{2} \\
\end{align*}

$(1)-(2)$,

$$\frac{2\alpha x}{a^2}+\frac{2\beta y}{b^2}+\frac{2\gamma z}{c^2}=
1-\lambda^2+\frac{\alpha^2}{a^2}+\frac{\beta^2}{b^2}+\frac{\gamma^2}{c^2}$$

which is the radical plane of the two ellipsoids.

The centre of section is:

$$
\frac
{1-\lambda^2+\dfrac{\alpha^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{\beta^2}{b^2}+\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2}}{2\left(
    \dfrac{\alpha^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{\beta^2}{b^2}+\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2}
  \right)}
\begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \\ \gamma \end{pmatrix}
$$

**Note briefly:**

No intersections if $\, \dfrac{\alpha^2}{a^2}+\dfrac{\beta^2}{b^2}+\dfrac{\gamma^2}{c^2}>(1+\lambda)^2$

Comment: Your two ellipsoids are not only similar; they are also oriented identically.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your reminding.